# Local server http communication and angular browser rendering

Tags: node.js, angular

I think I'm doing something completely the wrong way.

I have an Nodejs server running that read in a DB and serve with express some data via http locally (it has to only be accessed locally). It sends the data on localhost on some port (8080 for example). Then I have an angular app on the server that get these datas from an http request on localhost:8080 and display them. The angular app runs locally on localhost:4200.

I was building the entire stuff on my computer and that was working perfectly (I have no problem with CORS). Then I deployed it on a server, and I accessed it via ssh port forwarding. Basically I forward localhost:4200 on the server via ssh on my local computer on localhost:8090.

And my problem is that, when loading and executing the angular app in my browser via port redirection, it's doing a get request to localhost:8080. So it's trying to communicate with the localhost it's running on, which is the client itself.

If you understood my spaghetti situation, there is actually a dirty solution : redirect localhost:8080 on the server to localhost:8080 on the client.

Is there any way to do the get request server side and not in the client's browser so that localhost correspond to the server? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

I can sum up by : How can you access another local service on localhost on the server with angular app since it executes in the client browser and localhost will refer to client localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use any web server (such as nginx or apache2 or etc.) in your server and make use of proxy and reverse proxy with your node application, it will work

[angular2-router-and-express-integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41922574/angular2-router-and-express-integration/43818886#43818886)

Comment: I applied your solution with a proxy config on the dev tools (with --proxy-config option) and it worked like a charm! Thanks a lot! I don't really understand how the proxy make this possible but it works! I only have difficulties to configure nginx on production to make this work but I hope it will!

Comment: you need to configure(setting proxy and reverse proxy) routes as follows

1. "/ " to "localhost:4200/" (so that your angular app will run on port 80)
2. in angular app change your request route from "http://localhost:8080/" to "api/".
3. in nginx configure "/api/" to "localhost:8080/"

Comment: from the above thing your app will be running on port 4200 but it can open from 80(default port), and the request you made to node app will initially goes to localhost/api/some-route, after this web server will get this /api/ route and will divert your request to localhost:8080/some-route which is your node app. That is how whole communication usually works